# Babel: error in constructor with : on parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs, ionic2

I'm following some examples of an Angular 2 app which uses ES6.
All of them have classes with this syntax in the constructor:

```
export class SetPassword {
    constructor(nav: NavController, userService: UserService) {
        this.nav = nav;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

I have cloned an example project with all set up to transpile files, but every time I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/cbenseler/dev/apps/expressoapp/app/pages/setpassword/setpassword.js: Unexpected token (14:16)
  12 |  }
  13 | 
> 14 |  constructor(nav: NavController, userService: UserService) {
at Parser.pp.raise (/home/cbenseler/dev/apps/expressoapp/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/cbenseler/dev/apps/expressoapp/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2905:8)
```

In https://babeljs.io/repl/ this piece of code works> I guess this is some problem in my babel transpiler but I can't figure out what can be. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: That's not valid ES6, I _assume_ the repl has sth. like https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-flow/ included as well

Comment: I guess this is TypeScript :-/

Comment: Yes, this is TS or flow; ES6 doesn't do param types.